# How do you stop images / text moving on different resolutions on a webpage?

Tags: html, css

When I look at my webpage on a different sized display other than my laptop screen, such as a desktop screen or TV, the image and text are in a different position horizontally.

Here is the html and CSS for my text class:

```
 <h2><a class="files"> text</a></h2>




.files {
font-size: 20px;
font-family: arial;
left: 470px;
position: relative;
}
```

And the image:

```
    <div id="Hipload-Product" class="report">
    <img src="<?php echo $MainURL?>img/image1.png" alt="" />

    </div>



 .report img { top: 200px;
 margin-left: -500px;
 }
```

Also, why is it that when I go on the homepage of my site, the image takes about 4 seconds to appear?

Thanks

Comment: could you please provide the whole page source, not only the two fragments? also what do you mean by 'the image and text are in a different position horizontally'?

Comment: The image and text move to the left / right on the different displays. Do you want the css or html page? I can provide the css but the html page contains about 400 lines of php and html so I can't give that. Thanks

Comment: ok, and the h2 is before the div with the image, right? btw, why do you have that -500px margin there?

Comment: yeah the h2 is before the image div

Comment: and what are you trying to achieve? image on the left and the h2 on the right of it? i don't understand those absolute css values (in pixels) and the negative margin on that img... anyway, i would recommend using some kind of grid framework as Vasei suggests in his answer, my favourite being the Twitter Bootstrap http://getbootstrap.com/ the positioning will be much easier and more predictable

Answer (score 0):

You are using absolute positioning. For your page to be more organized in different monitor sizes it's better to use relative positioning. these two are described in [w3schools: css-positioning](http://www.w3schools.com/css/css_positioning.asp)
Another technique that would be helpful is using tables or grid systems to divide your page into some areas each of which containig specific elements. Take a look at [960 Grid System](http://960.gs/)

Comment: How? he has put `position:relative;`